# Removing The Result Button and Use Bind To Bind The Entry Field In Python

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Here Is The Main.py

```
from customtkinter import ALL
from JapQuiz import *

# Ctk Config
Ctk.set_appearance_mode("System")
Ctk.set_default_color_theme("blue")

class SwitchTheWritingStyle(Ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, frame, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.r = Ctk.IntVar()
        self.r.set(0)
        Ctk.CTkRadioButton(self,
                            variable = self.r,
                            text = "Hiragana",
                            value = 0,
                            width = 100,
                            font = Ctk.CTkFont("CascadiaCodeItalic",
                                                size = 20)).grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        
        Ctk.CTkRadioButton(self,
                            variable = self.r,
                            text = "Katakana",
                            value = 1,
                            width = 100,
                            font = Ctk.CTkFont("CascadiaCodeItalic",
                                                size = 20)).grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
            
        Ctk.CTkLabel(self, 
                text="Enter The Pron Of Given In English:", 
                font=Ctk.CTkFont("CascadiaCodeItalic",
                                size=20)).grid(column=0, row=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        
        x = JapQuiz(frame)

        self.pron = Ctk.CTkEntry(self, 
                                font=Ctk.CTkFont("CascadiaCodeItalic",
                                                size=20))
        self.pron.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=10, pady=10)        

    def getwritingmode(self):
        return self.r.get()
    
    def getpron(self):
        return self.pron.get()

class App(Ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        global resultframe
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Japanese Quiz")
        self.configure(background="black")

        px = 10
        py = 20
        cr = 10

        charachterframe = Ctk.CTkFrame(self, corner_radius = cr)
        charachterframe.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=px, pady=py)

        resultframe = Ctk.CTkFrame(self, corner_radius = cr)
        resultframe.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=px, pady=py)

        style = SwitchTheWritingStyle(self, frame=resultframe, corner_radius = cr)
        style.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=px, pady=py)

        x = JapQuiz(charachterframe)
        Ctk.CTkLabel(charachterframe,  
            text="Japanese Character", 
            font=Ctk.CTkFont("CascadiaCodeItalic",
                            size=20)).grid(column=2, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        # Buttons Implemented Here
        Ctk.CTkButton(charachterframe,
                    text="Generate Character", 
                    command=lambda: x.JapQuizRandomCharacter(style.getwritingmode()), 
                    font=Ctk.CTkFont("CascadiaCodeItalic",
                                    size=20)).grid(column=2,row=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        resultentry = Ctk.CTkButton(resultframe, 
                                  command=lambda: x.PronunciationCheck(style.getwritingmode(),
                                                                style.pron.get(),
                                                                resultframe), 
                                  text="Result",
                                  font=Ctk.CTkFont("CascadiaCodeItalic",
                                                   size=20))

        resultentry.grid(column=3,row=1, padx=10, pady=10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

And JapQuiz.py

```
import random as rand
import customtkinter as Ctk

class JapQuiz():
    def __init__(self, tkinter_root):
        self.root = tkinter_root
        self.lol = Ctk.CTkLabel(master=tkinter_root)
        japcharhir = ["あ","い","う","え","お","か","き","く","け","こ","さ","し","す","せ","そ","た","ち","つ","て","と","な","に","ぬ","ね","の","は","ひ","ふ","へ","ほ","ま","み","む","め","も","や","ゆ","よ","ら","り","る","れ","ろ","わ","を","ん"]
        japcharkat = ["ア","イ","ウ","エ","オ","カ","キ","ク","ケ","コ","サ","シ","ス","セ","ソ","タ","チ","ツ","テ","ト","ナ","ニ","ヌ","ネ","ノ","ハ","ヒ","フ","ヘ","ホ","マ","ミ","ム","メ","モ","ヤ","ユ","ヨ","ラ","リ","ル","レ","ロ","ワ","ヲ","ン"]
        z = ["a","i","u","e","o","ka","ki","ku","ke","ko","sa","shi","su","se","so","ta","chi","tsu","te","to","na","ni","nu","ne","no","ha","hi","fu","he","ho","ma","mi","mu","me","mo","ya","yu","yo","ra","ri","ru","re","ro","wa","wo","n"]
        self.dict_1 = dict(zip(japcharkat,z))
        self.dict_2 = dict(zip(japcharhir,z))

    def JapQuizRandomCharacter(self, mode):
        self.x = rand.randint(1,46)
        if mode == 0:
            int_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46]
            japchar = ["あ","い","う","え","お","か","き","く","け","こ","さ","し","す","せ","そ","た","ち","つ","て","と","な","に","ぬ","ね","の","は","ひ","ふ","へ","ほ","ま","み","む","め","も","や","ゆ","よ","ら","り","る","れ","ろ","わ","を","ん"]
            dict_1 = dict(zip(int_1,japchar))

            self.lol.destroy()
            self.lol = Ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.root, 
                                    text=f"{dict_1[self.x]}", 
                                    font=Ctk.CTkFont("CascadiaCodeItalic",
                                                        size=20))
            
            self.lol.grid(column=2,row=2)
            self.output = dict_1[self.x]

        elif mode == 1:
            int_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46]
            japchar = ["ア","イ","ウ","エ","オ","カ","キ","ク","ケ","コ","サ","シ","ス","セ","ソ","タ","チ","ツ","テ","ト","ナ","ニ","ヌ","ネ","ノ","ハ","ヒ","フ","ヘ","ホ","マ","ミ","ム","メ","モ","ヤ","ユ","ヨ","ラ","リ","ル","レ","ロ","ワ","ヲ","ン"]
            dict_1 = dict(zip(int_1,japchar))

            self.lol.destroy()
            self.lol = Ctk.CTkLabel(master=self.root, 
                                    text=f"{dict_1[self.x]}", 
                                    font=Ctk.CTkFont("CascadiaCodeItalic",
                                                        size=20))
            
            self.lol.grid(column=2,row=2)
            self.output = dict_1[self.x]
        else:
            ...

    def PronunciationCheck(self, mode, pro, root, event = None):
        global dict_1
        global dict_2

        if mode == 0:
            if pro == self.dict_2[self.output]:
                self.lol.destroy()
                self.lol = Ctk.CTkLabel(root, 
                                        text=f"You Are Right!", 
                                        font=Ctk.CTkFont("CascadiaCodeItalic",
                                                            size=20))
                
                self.lol.grid(column=3,row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
            else:
                self.lol.destroy()
                self.lol = Ctk.CTkLabel(root, 
                                        text=f"You Are Wrong!", 
                                        font=Ctk.CTkFont("CascadiaCodeItalic",
                                                            size=20))
                
                self.lol.grid(column=3,row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        elif mode == 1:
            if pro == self.dict_1[self.output]:
                self.lol.destroy()
                self.lol = Ctk.CTkLabel(root, 
                                        text=f"You Are Right!", 
                                        font=Ctk.CTkFont("CascadiaCodeItalic",
                                                            size=20))
                
                self.lol.grid(column=3,row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
            else:
                self.lol.destroy()
                self.lol = Ctk.CTkLabel(root, 
                                        text=f"You Are Wrong!", 
                                        font=Ctk.CTkFont("CascadiaCodeItalic",
                                                            size=20))
                
                self.lol.grid(column=3,row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        else:
            self.lol.destroy()
            self.lol = Ctk.CTkLabel(root, 
                                    text=f"Please Enter The Mode First", 
                                    font=Ctk.CTkFont("CascadiaCodeItalic",
                                                        size=20))
            
            self.lol.grid(column=3,row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
```

So, the question I want to ask is that to get the result if the pronunciation is right or wrong i have to press the result button but is there a way to use enter in the entry field and it will automatically run the command and there should be no use of the button?

[This Is The Button I Want To Remove!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEWa9.png)

To Use This App:

1. Select Your Writing Mode i.e. Katakana Or Hiragana
2. Click Generate Character
3. Enter Its Pronunciation In Small Letters In English
4. Click The Result Button To See If You Are Right Or Wrong

(I want to change the 4th step to "Press Enter To See If You Are Right Or Wrong!")

I tried to bind the key directly to the entry field but it gave a lot of different errors which when resolved didn't work either.

Comment: Try to bind the root window because when you think about it, the detection is not "made" by the entry widget but by the entiere app.